# Nested JSON parsing with Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am using [SwiftlyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to parse JSON. My JSON looks like this

```
{
“data”:[{
“id”:123,
“locations”:[{
    “lat”:345,
    “long”:678
},{
    “lat”:345,
    “long”:678
}],
”live”:yes
},{
“id”:123,
“locations”:[{
    “lat”:999,
    “long”:324
},{
    “lat”:865,
    “long”:765
}],
”live”:no
}],
“success”:true,
“status”: 200
}
```

I want to get every "lat" and "long" from "locations", pair them and show them in a table cell.

My code in Network Service looks like this

```
private func updateSearchResults(_ data: Data) {
    do {
        let json = try JSON(data: data) //successfully parsed data 
        let locations =  json["data"].arrayValue.map {$0["loactions"].arrayObject}

        print(locations) //locations array is printing out correctly
        for latlang in locations{
          if let lat = latlang["lat"]{
              print(lat) //ERROR here 
          }
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Error description: Cannot subscript a value of type '[Any]' with an index of type 'String'

Now, I know the error that I can't access locations array by giving string in index but I don't know how to access the "lat" and "long" from JSON. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This line looks like a typo `if let lat = latlang["late"]{` shouldn't it be `"lat"`, dropping the `e`?

Comment: What's the error that you get anyway?

Comment: Yes it was a typo. Corrected the question and added the error description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an `array` of locations(i.e, `Dictionary`) using `flatMap`. Then, access the values as,

```
if let locations =  json["data"].arrayValue.flatMap { $0["loactions"].arrayObject } as? [[String: Any]] {
   for latlang in locations {
      print(latlang["lat"])
      print(latlang["long"])
   }
}
```

---

Suggestion: Stop using `SwiftyJSON`. Use Codable and generate your model and parsing code using this [app](https://app.quicktype.io).